# What does continuity from below mean?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, continuity

I can't quite find any definitions of this, and i need it to understand a proof. An explanation or definition would be greatly aprreciated. tyvm:) Im not sure if it is relevant, but it is in regards to probabilty theory and measures.

It is used here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fmPg.png

Comment: maybe lower semicontinuous or continuous from the left (e.g. approaching from values smaller)

Comment: You should write another question in which you type what is in the image and contextualize your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\scrF}{\mathcal{F}}$
It would help to know where exactly you're seeing this being referenced, but I'll take a stab at it. Continuity from below is a standard property of measures.

> **Proposition (Continuity from below):** If $\mu$ is a measure on some measure space $(\Omega,\scrF)$ and $(E_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is an increasing sequence of sets in $\scrF$, then
> $$
> \mu \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n \right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mu(E_n).
> $$

This is exactly what continuity from below is, the intuition being that because the sequence of sets are increasing, the measure of the union in some sense "ascends" to the limit. Unless you are referring to something else, you could find this in any measure theory book. Also this is not reserved for probability measures, arbitrary measures and even signed measures will satisfy this.

If you want to prove it, let $(E_n)$ be an increasing sequence of sets in $\scrF$ and consider the sequenece of sets defined by $F_n = E_n \setminus E_{n-1}$ where we set $E_0 = \varnothing$. You should prove that the sequence $(F_n)$ is disjoint , it has the property that $\cup E_n = \cup F_n$ and that $E_n = F_1 \cup \dots \cup F_n$ for every $n \geq 1$. Then you can show that continuity from below holds.

For reference this is defined in Theorem 1.8 of Folland (pg. 26), and if you want only probability theory, in Theorem 2.1 of Billingsley (pg. 25).

Comment: I added a reference now. I understand what is going on until the last sentence, i cant quite understand why M(A_n)=0

Comment: Not enough to go off. Write out your issue in the question, what I've given is exactly what continuity from below means.